# How to use jQuery Ajax post response params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to use parameters that I receive in an Ajax response, but I'm receiving it as a simple string.

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: str
}).done(function(res){
    // res is a simple string
    // => ResponseCode=0&Description=OK
});
```

Lets say I need to use the Description parameter's value (OK).

Comment: Use the `dataType` attribute to receive the response in the desired format.

Comment: I may be wrong but will have to use dirty split and dig the value.. it will be better if you can improve the format of your response string..

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/369450). The response you're getting `res` contains URL query parameters. Look at the provided link to find solutions for parsing that.

Answer (score -3):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType : "json", // define type 
    data: str,
    error : function( er ){ console.log( e );},
    success: function( response ){

    console.log( response );
});
```

Comment: this should work an din reality it probably would work for JSON, but use json for your stuff cause it is documented as such. Helps avoid confusion.. I don't have a way to test any of this at now. But good stuff.

Comment: The OP is not using JSON.

Comment: @KAG The OP's response `ResponseCode=0&Description=OK` is not JSON. This is the format for URL query parameters. Setting *dataType* to `json` will cause an error because the response cannot be parsed as JSON.